# How to query nested objects in postman?

Tags: rest, mongoose, postman, nuxtjs3

How do I filter nested objects in postman?

I want to query the `country` dynamically

[image]

I tried many options but none of them works.

I am using nuxt js to Fetch data from the API

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Postman question - what does the API support to fetch nested objects?

Comment: My bad, the proper word of this I think should be filter instead of query.

Comment: Fetch the payload with axios or fetch and use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on it.